# Can IntelliJ auto-complete constructor parameters on "new" expression?

Tags: intellij-idea

If my class has a non-empty constructor, is it possible to auto-complete parameters in the `new` expression?

With Eclipse, if you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> when the cursor is between the parenthesis:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
```

it will find the appropriate parameters.

```
-->  MyClass myObject = new MyClass(name, value);
```

When I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd> after the `new`, Intellij shows me the constructors, but I can't choose one for auto-completion. Am I missing an option?

Comment: why isn't such a simple feature available out of the box when you press ctrl+space??

Comment: Why did you change the accepted answer in 2016 to one with three upvotes when the answer from 2011 has 116?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Intellij Idea 2016.3 you can use <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd>. It will ask you if you want to introduce the named argument for the argument you are on and all the followers.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Is it specific to a certain language?

Comment: I have tested in in Scala and Mac OSX, not sure about other languages/environment.

Comment: Most versions of Java that are in production use today don't support named arguments. Named arguments helper won't auto-complete the constructor anyway, it will just change the style of the already specified constructor invocation.

Comment: In case you switched to Kotlin by now, there's a plugin for that: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10942-kotlin-fill-class

Answer (score 126):

I usually start with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (`Parameter Info` action) to see what arguments are accepted (auto guess complete is way to error prone in my opinion). And if as in your case you want to fill in `name` type `n` a dropdown menu appears with all available variables/fields (etc) starting with `n` <kbd>Arrow Up/Down</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select name, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to select a method (or even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to be killed by suggestions;-), followed by `,` and `v` <kbd>Tab</kbd> for value.

Comment: For reference, with the OS X key bindings this is ⌘P and the name of the functionality is "parameter info" (from View > Parameter Info).

Answer (score 19):

Well I used the eclipse key map where **Parameter Info** is unassigned.
Here is how to change that:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Well there's the Ctrl+Shift+Space combination, which tries to come up with a set of possible arguments. And if you press the Ctrl+Shift+Space a second time, Idea tries find arguments which fit across multiple calls & conversions.

So in your example Ctrl+Shift+Space would almost certainly bring up the 'name' as suggestion. And the next Ctrl+Shift+Space would bring up 'value' as suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such possibility yet. As IDEA doesn't fill the arguments automatically, distinguishing the constructors in the lookup makes no sense. There's a request for that (http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-5496) although I sincerely believe such a behavior is too dangerous and error-prone.

Comment: Ctrl+P, Parameter info (within method call arguments).

Comment: I disagree - why would it be so dangerous that a user could at least opt to enable it? It is a very useful function and probably easy to implement it - so I don't see the value in not implementing this feature.

Comment: It's always funny when any vendor want to tell me what is a good or bad development behaviour.
And it makes very well sense because when I create a class, I need to choose which ctor to use. Otherwise ctors would not make sense.

Comment: Jens Nerche seems to have developed a plugin for this now, see https://github.com/kontext-e/AutoFillingCallArguments. It's added to the Intellij's plugin repo.

Comment: The Eclipse foundation apparently does not think this feature is "too dangerous and error-prone" as it's been in their IDE for years.  :)

Comment: Too dangerous? Don't use it. Simple and tidy.