# Autofill function parameters in Android Studio

Tags: android, parameters, autocomplete, android-studio

I've been working in Android Studio recently, and was wondering if there is a hot key / setting / method for autofilling function parameters after a function call is autocompleted.

For instance, if I type in db.query(), I would like the following to show upon the auto-completion of query:

```
db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
```

instead of just the function name with empty (but required) parameters:

```
db.query();
```

Comment: Coming from Xcode I would definitely expect that. A small help: Ctrl-P (Win) / CMD-P (Mac) will show parameters (but no autocompletion) -> https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **Kotlin**, there is a plugin called `Kotlin Fill Class`. After writing the parentheses, right click into it and select `Show Context Actions` (Shortcut `Alt + Enter`, in my case) and then `Fill function with dummy values`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio does not really provide auto completing your functions but you can show the parameters of the function in the other class by pressing `Crtl + P`. This opens a pop up with the names of the variables.

[This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815301/can-intellij-auto-complete-constructor-parameters-on-new-expression)