# Android studio code completion not working properly

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio version 0.9.3 Canary Build.

When I typed `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>()`, the editor did not provide code completion options for the method parameters instead it just displayed them in a balloon.  How do I enable the code completion list to appear for those suggestions. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+P, Parameter info (within method call arguments)

If you using MAC OS X, then use ⌘P and the name of the functionality is "parameter info" (from View > Parameter Info)

There's a nice explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815301/can-intellij-auto-complete-constructor-parameters-on-new-instruction)