# android studio auto complete: how to display constructors with parameters

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

The auto Complete in eclipse displays all constructors with parameters, but Android studio doesn't.

For example see the following screenshot in eclipse, it displays all constructors of Intent class.

[image]

While auto complete in android studio for Intent class is displayed without parameters as following.

[image]

How to change auto complete in android studio to display all constructors with parameters ?

Comment: Have you considered making a feature request at the AS issue tracker? I am personally crying over this.

Comment: Please accept the correct Answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Real answer to the Question:

It is also possible to show overloaded constructors by enabling a hidden option. Invoke the `Help | Find Action` menu item and type `Registry` to go to the Registry. Here enable the `java.completion.show.constructors` option.
[image: constructor overloads in completion]

Copied From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43639241/2920861

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Why isn't this enabled by default? Will make a lot of people's lives easier

Answer (score 44):

I usually start with `Ctrl+P` to see what arguments are accepted (auto guess complete is way to error prone in my opinion). And if as in your case you want to fill in name type n a `dropdown` menu appears with all available `variables/fields` (etc) starting with n `Arrow Up/Down` and Tab to select name, or `Ctrl+Space` to select a method (or even `Ctrl+Alt+Space` to be killed by suggestions;-), followed by , and v Tab for value.

File --> Keymap --> Main Menu --> Parameter Info --> Right Click --> Add keyboard short cut

I dont know whether it is added advantage or not  while creating a constructor (ctrl+shift+space) will give default constructor after that cursor stays within the parenthesis gives all parametrized constructor of a particular class without any short cut :)

in eclipse ctrl+space with give you all the constructors of class [image]

in android studio no need short cut key [image]:)

**You Can Use Eclipse Short Cut Keys in Android Studio Follow Below Process :
File -- > Settings -- > Keymap ---> under Keymaps Drop down Select Eclipse option**

Cheers

Comment: thanks, I appreciate you replying, however I do not want to straggle what shortcut is in a sequence of shortcuts. 
I ask if there is any way to make ctrl+space in android studio acts just like ctrl+space act in eclipse and display all constructors with parameters. I want to see all possibilities as options then I will choose the needed one.
is it possible?

Comment: Thanks, although this is not an alternative, only a poor workaround. But obviously one cannot expect much from Android Studio.
The original answer is here by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815301/can-intellij-auto-complete-constructor-parameters-on-new-expression

Answer (score 14):

After writing default constructor, press `Ctrl+P`. You will see list of possible parameters that can be fill in constructor.

Comment: CTRL+P wants to print!

Comment: @DanielHári Go to settings of Android Studio and change the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion -> Auto Popup in(ms) set it 10

Then you will see same behavior as eclipse

Comment: How it makes visible the constructors?

Comment: Well, you got an answer for that @LynAs?